# New to Rails and my JQuery UI DatePicker isn't showing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm diving into Rails and I'm following one of the Railscasts to add the DatePicker to my form, but when I click on the text field, the DatePicker doesn't pop up and I'm so new to this that I'm having a hard time figuring out how to troubleshoot it.

JS and CSS includes in my application.html.erb

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->    
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/plugins/fancy-type/screen',  :media => 'print' %>
 <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" %>

<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

Here's a snippet from my form...

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "drills", :action => "create"}, :method => "post") do %>
.
.
.
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag("Date Scheduled") %> <br />
  <%= text_field_tag(:scheduled_for) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag("Save") %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and my application js code where I link the DatePicker to the form

```
$(function() {
  $("#scheduled_for").datepicker();
});
```

All the rendered HTML looks fine, so I don't know what else to inspect.  Your thoughts?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: did you try this for simple html page i.e. without using any rails helpers?

Comment: inspect element your textfield tag, and double check if its id is "scheduled_for"

Comment: ok, I wanted to know that did you try datepicker with Jquery in any static HTML page which was not generated by rails, I suspect that you have include jqueryui.js before jQuery.js so jQueryUI might be dependent on jQuery so not executing properly. Another question is are you using jQuery with prototype? if yes, then it might caused a problem here.

Comment: @corroded, as I mentioned in the question, the resulting HTML code is correct.
@Naren, I removed the default Rail 3 rails.js (prototype) file and replaced it with the rails.js for jquery file.  Is that all I need to do to remove prototype?  Also, the jquery-ui.js file is being included after the jquery.js file.

Comment: ok, thanks all, that fixed it. i hadn't removed the prototype.js file and it was still being included. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the order that you load your js files.  You have to include first the jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery UI libraries, and then the application.js

In other words change to this :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" %>

<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't seem to fix it.  Can I ask why that should make a difference?

Comment: because the jQuery libraries has to be included in order to use it, and as is right now it run without it

Comment: thanks, eveevans, tho i don't still don't understand, if I'm including them using the javascript_include_tag, how do they get left out? thanks again.

Comment: I mean, you application.js load first, and it has to load after the jQuery libraries.

Comment: Also I agree with Naren, are you loading prototype? In that case you have to load jQuery with noConflict mode

Comment: I removed the default Rail 3 rails.js (prototype) file and replaced it with the rails.js for jquery file. Is that all I need to do to remove prototype?  Also, I just checked the rendered HTML and the application.js file is being loaded last.

Comment: ok, thanks all, that fixed it.  i hadn't removed the prototype.js file and it was still being included.  thanks again!